# Resize the content of a div based on how many objects are in the div

Tags: jquery, css, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am working on a site that needs to give a thumbnail preview of a report in ColdFusion8 and ColdFusion11.  The consensus is that we will search the xml source of the reports for items (list,chart,etc.) then put a png representation of that element in the thumbnail.  Since each report is unique in order,number, and type of report items, we need to have a div that will stay the same size (as it is a pop-up thumbnail) but each report item will resize based on how many others are in the same div.  Meaning if only one list, it will take up the whole div, but if two then each will take up exactly 50% of the alotted space, and so on.  I am not sure how to begin to tackle this issue, so if I'm barking up the wrong tree, please say so.  I have seen posts on dynamically sizing with css a single background image, but nothing where multiple images may or may not be in a particular "box" and the only thing that changes is the size of the; in this case pngs.

Here is all the hoopla i'm jumping through to find two types of report items (lists and charts) and how im currently displaying them:

The index.cfm calls the thumbs_CF8.cfc which returns the div with the thumbs image back to index.cfm

```
thumbs_CF8.cfc:

...
<!--- script to search and parse out items in order of xml doc --->
<cfscript> 



listInXml=ArrayNew(2);    


listInXml = XmlSearch(cleanedXml,"//node()[ local-name()='listColumns' or local-name()='combinationChart' or local-name()='dataSource'] ");    

     for (i = 1; i LTE ArrayLen(listInXml); i = i + 1)
    try{ elementsList[i][1] = (listInXml[i].XmlName); } catch (any e) {elementsList[i][1] = 'noName';}


      for (i = 1; i LTE ArrayLen(listInXml); i = i + 1)
    try{ elementsList[i][2] = (listInXml[i].XmlAttributes['name']); } catch (any e) {elementsList[i][2] = 'noXmlAttrib-Name';}




</cfscript>



<!--- loop to output pngs based on the elementsList --->

 <cfset thumbsBuckets = arrayNew(1)>

<cfloop index=i from="1" to="#arrayLen(elementsList)#" >

                <cfloop index=j from=1 to=2>
                    <cfset myArray[i][1] = #elementsList[i][1]# >
                    <cfset myArray[i][2] = #elementsList[i][2]# >
                </cfloop>


                  <cfif Find("listColumns",myArray[i][1])>


                       <cfset thumbsBuckets[i] = '<img tabindex="0" class="image" src="#Application.basepath#/images/list-icon.png" style="height: 46px; width:46px;">' >

                        <!--- labels for icons
                        <cfif Find("noXmlAttrib-Name",myArray[i][2])>
                            #myArray[i][1]#</br>
                        <cfelse>
                            #myArray[i][2]#</br>
                        </cfif> --->


                  <cfelseif Find("combinationChart",myArray[i][1])>


                        <cfset thumbsBuckets[i] = '<img tabindex="0" class="image" src="#Application.basepath#/images/Bar-chart-icon.png" style="height: 46px; width:46px;">' >

                        <!---
                        <cfif Find("noXmlAttrib-Name",myArray[i][2])>
                            #myArray[i][1]#</br>
                        <cfelse>
                            #myArray[i][2]#</br>
                        </cfif>
                            --->


                  <cfelse>

                        <cfset thumbsBuckets[i] = 'no icon'>

                      <!--- I didn't find a icon for #name# </br> --->

                  </cfif>



  </cfloop>


<!--- div bucket to put the thumbs into --->
                                             <div   >

                                                    <cfloop index=i from="1" to="#arrayLen(thumbsBuckets)#" >


                                                        <cfif #thumbsBuckets[i]# NEQ 'no icon'>
                                                        #thumbsBuckets[i]#
                                                        <cfelse>

                                                        </cfif>


                                                    </cfloop>   

                                                </div>

Index.cfm:
<!--- index.cfm where the div thumbs bucket comes back to get displayed --->

                                                                <div style="width:50%; height:30%"><!------ thumbs section - under construction --------------------->



                                                                            <div class="thumbsItemRow">

                                                                                <cfset xmlToParse = #reportResults.REPORT_XML# >


                                                                                <cftry> 

                                                                                <cfinvoke component="#thumbObj#" method="makeXML" reportTitle="#reportResults.COG_REPORT_TITLE#"   numVersion="#numVersion#" xmlToParse="#xmlToParse#" returnvariable="thumbs">

                                                                                <cfcatch>No thumbs!</cfcatch>

                                                                                </cftry> 

                                                                            </div>


                                                                <!------ end thumbs section ---------------------> </div>

                                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make your mark-up conditional based on how many images/charts you need to render in the box... something like:

```
<div class="chart-container num-charts-#arrayLen(myData.charts)#">

  <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(myData.charts)#" index="i">

    <div class="chart-item-container">
      <img src="#myData.charts[i].imgPath#">
    </div>

  </cfloop>

</div>
```

and then have some css:

```
.chart-item-container {
    width: 100%; /* default width */
}

.num-charts-1 .chart-item-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.num-charts-2 .chart-item-container {
  width: 50%;
}

.num-charts-3 .chart-item-container {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.chart-item-container img {
   max-width: 100%; /* ensure image stretches to fill available space */
}
```

Comment: very interesting; I will have to try this out, and let you know.

Comment: this works great! I have an clarity question- if it needs a new post just say so; how do I keep the .chart-item-conatiner s from lining up like a column instead of a row that wraps to next line? I set margin to 0% on both the container and inner num-charts classes; still no joy.

Comment: So I understand... are you saying you want all the charts on one row, or you want them to stack vertically in a column?

Comment: I want them all in one row; and then to wrap if they need to

Comment: They stopped being a column when I changed the div tags to a tags; but only in chrome; i need them to do the same behavior in ie 9 and chrome.

Comment: ignore that ie 9 stuff; my manager just said we don't have to do that after all, yay!

Comment: Try putting display: block on the anchor tags, since divs are display block by default and anchors aren't. If that doesn't do the trick, probably best to ask a new question and setup a simplified, stripped down version of your issue in jsfiddle so we can see it running in a browser. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another just as valid and maybe even a little easier answer I found was to use Bootstrap.js.  I know I asked for css, but after trying to get the objects to line up properly, I decided to go with bootstrap.  In bootstrapt Im doing the following:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                                <!--- notes:
                                                    Bootstrap allows for the classes container-fluid, row-fluid,and col-md-#
                                                    to combine to allow the icons to resize based on how many there are and
                                                    to wrap onto a row of 1-12 evenly sized images.  The mdSize is taking the 
                                                    total count of thumbs and transforming it to a even divisor of 12.
                                                    In order for the wrapping to work each image width must be the same.
                                                    --->

                                                    <cfset thumbArraySize = #arrayLen(thumbsBuckets)# >

                                                    <cfset mdSize = (Int(round(#thumbArraySize#*12)/12)/12) >

                                                    <cfloop index=i from="1" to="#arrayLen(thumbsBuckets)#" >


                                                        <div class="col-md-#mdSize# chart-item-container" >
                                                            <cfif #thumbsBuckets[i]# NEQ 'no icon'>
                                                            #thumbsBuckets[i]#
                                                            <cfelse>

                                                            </cfif>
                                                        </div>




                                                    </cfloop>   

                                                </div>
                                        </div>


                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                                </div>
```

Now the only trouble is getting the unknown amounts of thumb icons to come out in even expressions of 12 such that any number less than 12 will be converted to a 1-12 representation of how much space it needs. 1 being the least and 12 being the most.  Which is opposite of the count of thumbs.  If there is only 1 thumb, the number needs to be 12, but if there are 12 or more the number will need to be 1.  However, that's a question for another post/day.  Hope this helps!